# Ansible: using "become" with "import_role"

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using `import_role` in my playbooks to run roles at specific points throughout my tasks. Some of the imported roles require elevated permissions, so I have been trying to use `become: yes` with them, with mixed results.

Here is an example of how I'm using `import_role`:

```
---
- import_role:
    name: geerlingguy.redis
  become: yes
```

Tasks within the imported role seem to run without issue, though with some roles that doesn't work either.

One of the consistent areas I run into problems is with the handlers in imported roles, that do not seem to receive the `become: yes` statement because they throw "Authentication required" errors. I end up having to copy their handlers inside whatever role I'm writing.

I am running Ansible version `2.5.0`.

How can I consistently and reliably pass `become` through to imported roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a series of bugs in 2.5.0 that are related to inheritance and I think that's what you're hitting here. Unfortunately the fix wasn't found in time for the 2.5.1 release but there should be a resolution for this in the 2.5.2 release.

Comment: Here's the pull requests with the fixes thus far. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pulls?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+author%3Asivel+project%3Aansible%2Fansible%2F17